# How to store and retrieve JSON data into local storage?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have this code:

```
var string = '{"items":[{"Desc":"Item1"},{"Desc":"Item2"}]}';
localStorage.setItem('added-items', JSON.stringify(string));
```

This code will use localStorage.

Here is now the code to get the stored data:

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('added-items');
```

My problem now is, how can i get the size of the data items? answer must be 2.

How can i get the "Item1" and "Item2"?

I tried `retrievedObject[0][0]` but it is not working.

And how to add data on it? 
so it will be

```
{"items":[{"Desc":"Item1"},{"Desc":"Item2"},{"Desc":"Item3"}]}
```

Can I use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: seems you need doulbe parse

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var string = '{"items":[{"Desc":"Item1"},{"Desc":"Item2"}]}';
localStorage.setItem('added-items', JSON.stringify(string));
```

`stringify` means, take an `object` and return its presentation as a `string`.
What you have, is already a string and not a JSON object.

The opposite is `JSON.parse` which takes a `string` and turns it into an `object`.

Neither of them have anything to do with getting the size of an array. When properly coding JavaScript you almost never use `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify`. Only if *serialization* is explicitly wanted.

Use `length` for the size of the array:

```
var obj = {"items":[{"Desc":"Item1"},{"Desc":"Item2"},{"Desc":"Item3"}]}
console.debug(obj.items.length);
```

Comment: i get the Item1 with this, object.items[0].Desc. But how can i add {"Desc":"Item3"]}?

Comment: `var foo = {"Desc":"Item3"}; items.push(foo);`

Comment: But he does explicitly want serialization in this case--in order to write it into local storage.

Answer (score 8):

```
// THIS IS ALREADY STRINGIFIED
var string = '{"items":[{"Desc":"Item1"},{"Desc":"Item2"}]}';

// DO NOT STRINGIFY AGAIN WHEN WRITING TO LOCAL STORAGE
localStorage.setItem('added-items', string);

// READ STRING FROM LOCAL STORAGE
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('added-items');

// CONVERT STRING TO REGULAR JS OBJECT
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

// ACCESS DATA
console.log(parsedObject.items[0].Desc);
```

Answer (score 6):

To bring clarity to future people that may stumble across this question and found the accepted answer to not be everything you hoped and dreamed for:

I've extended the question so that the user may either want to input a `string` or `JSON` into `localStorage`.

Included are two functions, `AddToLocalStorage(data)` and `GetFromLocalStorage(key)`.

With `AddToLocalStorage(data)`, if your input is not a `string` (such as `JSON`), then it will be converted into one.

`GetFromLocalStorage(key)` retrieves the data from `localStorage` of said `key`

The end of the script shows an example of how to examine and alter the data within JSON. Because it is a combination of objects and array, one must use a combination of `.` and `[]` where they are applicable.

```js
var string = '{"items":[{"Desc":"Item1"},{"Desc":"Item2"}]}';
var json = {"items":[{"Desc":"Item1"},{"Desc":"Item2"},{"firstName":"John"},{"lastName":"Smith"}]};

localStorage.setItem('added-items', AddToLocalStorage(string));
localStorage.setItem('added-items', AddToLocalStorage(json));

// this function converts JSON into string to be entered into localStorage
function AddToLocalStorage(data) {
  if (typeof data != "string") {data = JSON.stringify(data);}
  return data;
}

// this function gets string from localStorage and converts it into JSON
function GetFromLocalStorage(key) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
}

var myData = GetFromLocalStorage("added-items");

console.log(myData.items[2].firstName)    // "John"

myData.items[2].firstName = ["John","Elizabeth"];
myData.items[2].lastName = ["Smith","Howard"];

console.log(myData.items[2])    // {"firstName":["John","Elizabeth"],"lastName":["Smith","Howard"]}

console.log(myData.items.length)    // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` is definitely the best way to create an object but I just want to add if that doesn't work (because of lack of support), `obj = eval('(' + str + ')');` should work.  I've had a problem with a HTML to PDF converter in the past that didn't include `JSON.parse` and `eval` did the trick.  Try `JSON.parse` first.

Access your object: `obj.items[0].Desc;`

Comment: This answer proposes a bad solution to something that is not even the problem.

Comment: I reiterated that `JSON.parse` is the best way more than once and gave an additional method in the event it was needed.

Comment: In what environment is `JSON.parse` not supported?

Comment: That application allows you to use JavaScript but doesn't include JSON.parse.  The eval method works instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
var object = Json.parse(retrievedObject);
```

Now you can access it just like an array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

If you need more help i have some previous code where i am reading Json from local storage and making a form from that json. This code will help in understanding how to traverse that array

Json stored in localstorage

```js
{"form":[{"element":"input", "type":"text","name":"name","value":"value","min":"2","max":"10"}]}
```

JavaScript to read that json

```js
function readJson(){
    if(!form_created){
        add_form();
    }
    var fetched_json = localStorage.getItem("json");
    var obj=JSON.parse(fetched_json);
    for(var i=0; i<obj.form.length;i++){
        var input = document.createElement(obj.form[i].element);
        input.name = obj.form[i].name;
        input.value = obj.form[i].value;
        input.type = obj.form[i].type;
        input.dataset.min = obj.form[i].min;
        input.dataset.max = obj.form[i].max;
        input.dataset.optional = obj.form[i].optional;
        
        form.insertBefore (input,form.lastChild);
    }
    alert(obj.form[0].name);
}
```

Comment: how can i access it? i tried object[0][0][1] but it return undefined

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know if you need any help

Comment: try 
object.items[0].Desc

Comment: This is wrong. Since he has stringified a string, to access it as a normal array, he would need to parse it **twice**, or skip the call to `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @torazaburo I just told how to get json from local storage , parse it and traverse the resulting array. As the question says "How to store and retrieve JSON data into local storage?"

So basically the downvote is not justified.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong. `var object = Json.parse(retrievedObject);` parses the data in local storage back into its original form, which is a string. It needs to be parsed yet another time to turn it into an object that can accessed in the normal way.