# fetching JSON array data from localstorage and displaying it in the html dynamically

Tags: jquery, local-storage, json-api

I have a created a form page with input fields "fname","emailId","phoneNo".
No I am creating a JSON array and storing the details in the local storage like this:

```
<script>

    var jsonArr=[];

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#addVendor').submit(function(){

            var fname=$('#addVendor').find('input[name="first_name"]').val();
            var emailId=$('#addVendor').find('input[name="email_id"]').val();
            var phoneNo=$('#addVendor').find('input[name="phone_no"]').val();

            var jsonObj={};
            jsonObj["fname"]=fname;
            jsonObj["emailId"]=emailId;
            jsonObj["phoneNo"]=phoneNo;

            jsonArr.push(jsonObj);

            localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(jsonArr));


        });

    });

</script>
```

Now in the display page I am fetching this localStorage object and displaying it.

```
<script>

var jsonArr;
$(document).ready(function(){


    jsonArr=localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    jsonString=JSON.parse(jsonArr);


    if(jsonArr!=null)
        {


    for(i=0; i<jsonString.length;i++)
        {

        var display=display+"<p>"+jsonString[i][i]+"</p>";



        }
     display+="<br>"

     $('div').html(display);

        }


    $('#addVendorbutton').click(function(){

        window.open("addVendor.jsp","_self",false,"");
    });
});
</script>
```

Now what I want is that the new details I enter in the form page should add-on in the localstorage object and it should display in the display page.
But the latest details which I enter in the form page are only getting stored in the localstorage and it is not storing the earlier details.
And whatever is getting displayed is "undefined".
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493531/how-to-store-and-retrieve-json-data-into-local-storage

Comment: I am able to fetch the parameters of JSON array which is in this format:[{"fname":"abc","emailId":"abc","phoneNo":"852"}]     Now when I am adding  another JSON object into the array, it is overwriting the object. How can I add the object without overwriting it.

Comment: If I have the json object myJson =[{"fname":"abc","emailId":"abc","phoneNo":"852"}];   Then I can simply do myJson[0].favoriteTeam = 'Patriots';   Does that help?